# iPhone 6s Authentication Required error will not go away

Tags: iphone, password, authentication

I recently updated my phone to version 10.1.1, and ever since I have gotten the attached error.  i enter my iTunes username and password and I still get the error.  I have tried restarting the phone as well.  How do i make this go away?

My carrier is Verizon

[image]

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: why is this happening and how can i make it go away.

Comment: Is that a genuine Apple dialog?  I don't recall 'password will be sent in the clear' or a full url (iosapps?) being displayed.  Maybe I've just never seen it but it looks odd.  Could it be similar to [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179788/88313)?